# How to push rename file in git

Tags: git, github

- Earlier my file name is MethodOverloadingConcept.java
- I updated the code and change the file name to MeetingRoom.java and
  Class Name    MeetingRoom.
- checked git status
- How can i commit the rename file commit i directly fire add, commit,& push command but nothing is updated in git

`$ git status`

On branch Palak_Assignment27
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Palak_Assignment27'.

> Changes to be committed:   (use "git restore --staged ..." to
> unstage)
> renamed:    src/palakSJun20/MethodOverloadingConcept.java -> src/palakSJun20/MeetingRoom.java
>
> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add ..." to update
> what will be committed)   (use "git restore ..." to discard
> changes in working directory)
> modified:   src/palakSJun20/MeetingRoom.java

- While Pushing it is showing this

`$ git push`

Enumerating objects: 8, done.

Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.

Delta compression using up to 4 threads

Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.

Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.46 KiB | 374.00 KiB/s, done.

Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0

**remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), completed with 3 local objects.
remote: This repository moved. Please use the new location:**

Answer (score 2):

Your git status says that you have changes not staged for commit.
You need to run `git add src/palakSJun20/MeetingRoom.java`, then create a commit, push it ...

The easiest way is to rename a file is by using git itself.

```
git mv MethodOverloadingConcept.java MeetingRoom.java
```

Then you can commit the change using `git commit`.

And then after you can push the new commit using `git push`.

Comment: What if i already change the file name via eclipse and committing the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could tell git to remove it (after the fact) and then add the new file.

```
git rm original-file-path
git add new-path
```

Answer (score 1):

`remote: This repository moved. Please use the new location:`

This actually seems *unrelated* to your file move/rename. It says the "origin" repository location has changed.

Compare your `git remote get-url origin` to the "new location" specified by the message and correct it with `git remote set-url origin <new address>` (replace `<new address>` with the new location specified by the reply).

After that you should be able to push again.

---

With regards to the file being renamed: Based on your `git status` output it seems you didn't even commit that rename yet. So it wouldn't be pushed anyway.

However if you want to stage your file changes for commit use `git add -p` and say `y` (*yes*) to the changes you want to add to the commit.

After that you can verify the changes prepared for commit with `git diff --staged` (you may have to use page up/down to look at changes and to press `q` key to quit looking at it).

If everything looks alright use `git commit` to create the commit.

After that you may want to double-check your commit by looking at it with `git show`.

If your commit looks the way you want, use `git push origin HEAD` to push your locally created commit(s) to the origin repository.

(The "origin HEAD" part makes sure you only push the current branch, not all of them)

However, as mentioned above it seems your repository ("*origin*") has moved, so you will have to adjust its address before you can push.